# How can I read and write PNG files to my database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got small userprofile images (5kB) that I want to store in the database. But I'm unsure of the datatype. varbinary(6000)? og maybe binary(6000)? Maybe use (MAX)?

And how do I go about writing and reading a image? Could I simply use INSERT and the bytearray from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might as well use `varbinary(max)`. If you *know* the size is much much smaller, it *can* sometimes be useful to keep it restricted - this allows things like in-row data optimizations; however, for a 5k image, that isn't going to be useful; the `(max)` types will therefore be much more convenient.

Yes, you can just use regular `insert`, `select` and `byte[]` for that kind of size. There *is* an "append in a loop" / "read in a loop" approach you can use for *huge* files (multi-megabyte, or gigabyte), but you don't need that here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blob` (Binary Large Object) to store image in your database see: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx)

> BLOB is a generic term that refers to the text, ntext, and image data types, which typically contain documents and pictures.

**edit:** as remarked by Marc Gravell:

> "text, ntext, and image data types": they have all been obsolete for many years; "varchar(max), nvarchar(max) and varbinary(max) data types" would be vastly preferable

for example:

```
  byte[] image = GetImage(photoFilePath);

  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){

      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (Image) " +
        "Values(@Image)", connection); 

      command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, image.Length).Value = image;

      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

And the `GetImage()` method:

```
public static byte[] GetImage(string filePath)
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

    byte[] image = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

    reader.Close();
    stream.Close();

    return image;
}
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Jason94 does it solve your problem? Can you mark the answer as resolved?

Comment: Re mention of "text, ntext, and image data types": they have all been obsolete for many years; "varchar(max), nvarchar(max) and varbinary(max) data types" would be vastly preferable

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your remark ! i will edit my answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can use data type `image` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Yes, you could simply use `insert` to add binary data.
There is the sample:

`insert into binary_file (binary_file_id, binary_data, file_name)
 values (@binary_file_id, @binary_data, @file_name)`,

where `@binary_data` is byte array

Comment: `image` is deprecated; `varbinary(max)` has been preferred for many years